# How to optimally apply resize on large data in ACE editor?

Tags: css, flexbox, editor, ace-editor

I am using ace-editor in my angular app as a JSON editor, ace editor has a feature to dynamically resize based on the data.
When I have data within 1.5k lines it works seamlessly post that the chrome browser get hang, noticed that the CPU utilization is also high

Can any help me to identify how can I resolve this issue or any work around?

If it is an styling issue can anyone suggest how to fit the editor?

**Resize logic:**

```
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.codeEditor.setOptions({
      maxLines: this.codeEditor.getSession().getScreenLength(),
      autoScrollEditorIntoView: true
    });
    this.codeEditor.resize();
  }
```

**editor.ts:**

```
import {
  Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter,
  OnChanges, SimpleChanges
} from '@angular/core';

import * as ace from 'ace-builds';
import 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-json';
import 'ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-github';

const THEME = 'ace/theme/github';
const LANG = 'ace/mode/json';

export interface EditorChangeEventArgs {
  newValue: any;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-editor',
  templateUrl: './editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editor.component.css']
})
export class EditorComponent implements OnChanges {
  @ViewChild('codeEditor') codeEditorElmRef: ElementRef;
  private codeEditor: ace.Ace.Editor;

  @Input() jsonObject;
  @Input() readMode;
  @Output() change = new EventEmitter();

  data: any;
  mode: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

    for (const properties of Object.keys(changes)) {
      if (properties == 'jsonObject') {
        const currentJSONObject = changes[properties];
        if (currentJSONObject.currentValue && currentJSONObject.firstChange == false)
          this.codeEditor.setValue(JSON.stringify(currentJSONObject.currentValue, null, '\t'), -1);
        else if (currentJSONObject.currentValue == null && currentJSONObject.firstChange == false)
          this.codeEditor.setValue("");
        else
          this.data = currentJSONObject.currentValue
      }
      if (properties == 'readMode') {
        const currentReadMode = changes[properties];
        if (currentReadMode.firstChange == false)
          this.codeEditor.setReadOnly(currentReadMode.currentValue);
        else
          this.mode = currentReadMode.currentValue
      }
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const element = this.codeEditorElmRef.nativeElement;
    const editorOptions: Partial<ace.Ace.EditorOptions> = {
      highlightActiveLine: true,
      displayIndentGuides: true,
      highlightSelectedWord: true,
    };
    this.codeEditor = ace.edit(element, editorOptions);
    this.codeEditor.setTheme(THEME);
    this.codeEditor.getSession().setMode(LANG);
    this.codeEditor.setShowFoldWidgets(true);
    this.codeEditor.setHighlightActiveLine(true);
    this.codeEditor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
    if (this.data)
      this.codeEditor.setValue(JSON.stringify(this.data, null, '\t'), -1);
    this.codeEditor.setReadOnly(this.readMode);
    if (this.mode)
      this.codeEditor.setReadOnly(this.mode);
  }

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.codeEditor.setOptions({
      maxLines: this.codeEditor.getSession().getScreenLength(),
      autoScrollEditorIntoView: true
    });
    this.codeEditor.resize();
  }

  onChange(updatedJSON) {
    this.change.emit({ newValue: updatedJSON });
  }

}
```

**editor.html:**

```
<div ace-editor #codeEditor [autoUpdateContent]="true" [durationBeforeCallback]="1000" (textChanged)="onChange($event)"
    (change)="onChange(codeEditor.value)" class="editor">
</div>
```

**Editor CSS property:**

```
.editor {
    min-height: 750px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Using editor component across the application by simply adding following tag in HTML body

```
<app-editor [jsonObject]="data" [readMode]="readMode" (change)="onChange($event)"></app-editor>
```

Comment: why do you want to set large value to maxLines it is meant to be small otherwise the virtual viewport optimization of ace does not work.

Comment: @auser in some cases the data which I am receiving from backend upon a rest api call consists of >2k-3k lines of JSON body

Comment: that's ok, but why do you want to use maxLines in that case instead of using editor scrollbar? The whole thing is not going to be visible on the screen anyway.

Comment: thanks @auser yes tried the same approach, so to avoid multiple scroll bar (browser and editor) initially I disabled browser scrolling and relied on editor scroll bar but that lead to hide some of the json content.To fix that I tried adjusting max-height (eg 750px) value but this caused uneven editor size across multiple systems (windows, mac, different screen size) . Edited the post added CSS property

Comment: you can use `height: 100%`, or flex, or window.onresize to set the correct height to the editor, Basically the all the same techniques you would use to set size of an empty div. I can give you working code snippet, if you give a link to a full app, because solution depends on the rest of the page, not ace editor itself.